# Install app from google play using qr code

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, uri

I want to create a qr code that when people scan that qr code, their phone will install my app from google play. It is easy to create a qr code that shows a link to my app in google play, but it will require user to do some more steps to install my app. Is there any way to improve this process?

Answer (score 0):

Logically, it is desirable for QR to open your app's page on Google Play.
Then the user can upload it with the "Upload" button, if he wishes.
This is the correct and expected scenario for the user.